# Can I use "this" in mapMutations spread inside Vue instance methods?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, this, vuex, vuex-modules

I want to set Vuex mutations as follows:

```
export default {
    props: {
        store: String
    },
    methods: {
        ...mapMutations({
            changeModel: `${this.store}/changeModel`
        })
    }
}
```

But I catch the error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'store' of undefined

How do I correctly use **props** inside the module mutation name?

I want to map `this.$store.commit('form1/changeModel')`, where `form1` is set from **props**.

Comment: What's wrong with `...mapMutations(['changeModel'])`? Do you want to map `this.$store.commit('changeModel')` - or something else?

Comment: I want to map `this.$store.commit('form1/changeModel')`, where `form1` is set from props.

Comment: @mcmimik Why are you using mutations directly in your component instead of actions to begin with?

Comment: @BennettDams You're right, actions should be used here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vuex helper `mapMutations` can be used with a function which works with `this`.

There does not seem to be a doc for this, but the Vuex unit test [helpers.spec.js](https://github.com/vuejs/vuex/blob/dev/test/unit/helpers.spec.js#L136) illustrates the pattern.

```js
const vm = new Vue({
  store,
  methods: mapMutations({
    plus (commit, amount) {
      commit('inc', amount + 1)
    }
  })
})
```

As a bonus, the function allows passing a parameter to the mutation, which is a common requirement.

Your code changes would be:

```js
export default {
  props: {
    store: String
  },
  methods: {
    ...mapMutations({
      changeModel(commit) { commit(`${this.store}/changeModel`) }
    })
  }
}
```

The call within your component is just `changeModel()` - mapMutations is taking care of injecting the `commit` parameter.

Note, I am not sure this is adding much except some extra noise (compared to a simple `this.$store.commit()`), but perhaps your requirement is more complicated than the example code.

Comment: Very nice. If you have the time, this would be a good documentation feature request to add to their issues list.

Comment: [the API guide for  mapMutations](https://vuex.vuejs.org/api/#mapmutations) does introduce this.

Answer (score 3):

I think there is no way to bind this on mapActions. But you can call it with `$store.dispatch`

```
methods: {
  changeModel() {
    this.$store.dispatch(`${this.store}/changeModel`);
  }
}
```

Comment: or even `this.$store.commit()` which is what you would use for a mutation

Answer (score 1):

It is not exaclty the solution that you asked but its effect is the same. As the mutation is a variable parameter, it is obvious to put it into a function as an input parameter instead of changing the mutation name. I would create an action in the store like this:

```
changeModel ({dispatch, commit, rootGetters}, mutationName) {
 commit(`${mutationName}/changeModel`, {}, {root: true})
})
```

And I would use this action in the component passing the mutationName into it.